# Is it possible to disable negative indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am developing the game connect 4 and i need to rid of negative indexing because it causes the game to act funny. Basically, the column a player accesses is based on a group of list combined into one single list to form an array. e.g

```
    grid1 = ['A','B','C','1']
    grid2 = ['D','E','F','2']
    grid3 = ['G','H','I','3']
    grid4 = ['J','K','L','4']

    # Now if we combine all three lists, we get
    Total_Grid = [['A','B','C','1']
                  ['D','E','F','2']
                  ['G','H','I','3']
                  ['J','K','L','4']]
    # We have a total of 4 columns and 4 rows in this grid
    # Here is the format of how we access values in list Total_Grid[row][col]
```

So to access letter 'G', we do Total_Grid[2][0]. because 'G' is in row 2, column 0. Drawing out the actual grid, we have:

```
    |  |  |  |  |
    -------------
    |  |  |  |  |
    -------------
    |  |  |  |  |
    -------------
    |  |  |  |  |
    -------------
    # As you can see, the grid is 4x4
```

Now because in connect 4, you don't get to choose what row the counter goes in, (it usually drops to the bottom of the grid), we will designate a value for row.

```
    row = 3
    # Lets ask the user for input
    col = input("What column would you like to drop your counter in? ")
    # let's say user inputs 3, the counter will drop to [3][3] in the grid
    col = 3

    |   |   |   |   |
    -----------------
    |   |   |   |   |
    -----------------
    |   |   |   |   |
    -----------------
    |   |   |   | X |
    -----------------
```

My problem now arises because for instance, if the user enters a negative number for the column value, it still works because it indexes backward but i want to disable this because it messes up the game when the AI tries to block the player from connecting 4 dots

Comment: Have you tried `if i < 0`?

Comment: Which do you want? An error, or ignore it? You mention both.

Comment: Can you change the code?, I mean, can you replace `print` for any other custom method?

Comment: @roganjosh i want python to ignore it

Comment: What do you mean "python" should ignore it???

Comment: basically, i have a list of items which are accessible by indexing. If I want to access the item e.g.  list = [1,2,3,4,5] to access value at index 2, we do print(list[2]) which prints out the number '3'. Now if i do print(list[2-6]), it will also print out 2 even though 2-6 is a negative number

Comment: @Rudeboiiezuronye so you always want a positive number to be returned? Using abs() will always give a positive number i.e abs(3-4) returns 1.

Comment: @Rudeboiiezuronye So you want to prevent a negative number from being used as an index? What should happen in case there *is* a negative number?

Comment: Yes. I want to disable negative indexing. Just as python gives you an out of range error if you try to access a list item with an index number that's too high, I want python to do the same if you try o index with a number below 0

Comment: ok, so thats really the question you're asking. What is the exact calculation you are doing? Can you provide an exact example? I guess the code above is just a made up example?

Comment: Yes the code above is an example. The actual code is part of a game i am developing for a project. Connect 4. The code itself is huge and complicated. I'm not sure how exactly i can put it on here plus stack flow won't let me ask another question lol

Comment: ok, how about just the bit you need help with? Could you edit your question to include those 4 or 5 lines, just so we can see what indexing and calculation you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

You might encapsulate your check and print functions into one callable function:

```
def print_only_if_non_negative(x):
    if x >= 0:
        print(x)

for i in range(5):
    print_only_if_non_negative(i-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5):
    if i<0:
        print('ERROR:VALUE IS NEGATIVE')
        pass
    else:
        # Do something
```

Comment: but `i` cannot be < 0  in that loop...

Comment: In this specific example then yes, and there won't be a problem. In general use where a list contains positive and negative numbers, this will catch it